# EntityFramework with Amazon EC2

Tags: .net, cloud, entity-framework-4.3

is it possible to use EntityFramework in an ASP.NET application on Amazon's EC2?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why no one ever answered this simple question...

Yes, Of course! The fact that the servers are running in EC2 is irrelevant. This is probably true for 99% of all applications. By this I mean that where you put the servers doesn't matter. It could be in EC2, it could be at another hosting provider, it could be in your basement. The main reason people choose EC2 is for the ease of scaling applications large and small, the speed in which you can provision new servers, and the relatively low cost. (There are many other reasons too.)